# reading non-text file in c++

Tags: c++, file, c++14

I open the mp3 file by mistake with notepad++ ( Open with ) and show the entire file in text inside the notepad it was so cool.
since I am learning c++ again, I told myself let write a program that opens any file inside the console and display their content on the console so I begin my code like this :

```
int readAndWrite() {

    string filename(R"(path\to\a\file)");

    ifstream file(filename);



    string line;

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '"
             << filename << "'" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (getline(file, line)){
        cout << line;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but it only shows 3 or 4 lines of the file and then exits the program I check my notepad++ again and find out about 700,000 line is in there.
I  told myself maybe there is a character inside the file so I start writing the above code with the below changes. instead of displaying the file let's wrote inside a text file.

```
int readAndWrite() {

    string filename(R"(path\to\a\file)");
    string filename2(R"(path\to\a\file\copy)");

    ifstream file(filename);
    ofstream copy(filename2);


    string line;

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '"
             << filename << "'" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (getline(file, line)){
        copy << line;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and again the same results. next try I give up on reading the file line by line so I start copying with this function.

```
void copyStringNewFile(ifstream& file, ofstream& copy)
{
    copy << file.rdbuf();
}
```

and their results did not change a bit.
At this point, I told myself the problem is from file maybe and it is kinda is because when I use a simple text file all of the above codes work.

Comment: Just a hunch, but does it make a difference if you change `ifstream file(filename);` to `ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);`?

Comment: In any case, `path\to\a\file\copy` will not work since `file` is not a directory.

Comment: It could be that the MP3 file has an EOF character inside it somehow, have you tried running it on different files? Perhaps some simple text file containing a few lines of normal text?

Comment: @jamit /@/ted-lyngmo no there is no difference betwenn  ios::binary and the copy file get created even when I removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all other non-text files, `mp3` files don't contain *lines* so you shouldn't use `std::getline`. Use [`istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`ostream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write). You can use [`istream::gcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to check how many characters that was actually read.

Since you are dealing with non-text files, also open the files in [`binary`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) mode.

You should also test if opening both files works - that is, both the input and the output file.

Example:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int readAndWrite() {
    std::string filename(R"(path\to\a\file)");
    std::string filename2(R"(path\to\a\file_copy)");

    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if(!file) {
        std::cerr << '\'' << filename << "': " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::ofstream copy(filename2, std::ios::binary);
    if(!copy) {
        std::cerr << '\'' << filename2 << "': " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char buf[1024];
    while(file) {
        file.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
        // write as many characters as was read above
        if(!copy.write(buf, file.gcount())) {
            // write failed, perhaps filesystem is full?
            std::cerr << '\'' << filename2 << "': " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main() {
    return readAndWrite();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I test your code again only a few lines get copied. original file is 1mb and copy file is about 1kb

Comment: @Milad There are no _lines_. This code _should_ produce an exact copy of the file you read from. Are you sure you are not looking at an old copy of the output file?

Comment: I copy-paste your code in my main program the result as I said the original file is more than 1Mb but the copy file is about 322 byte

Comment: @Milad Please remove the copy file first and rerun the program. Btw, is your filesystem full? I added a new test to the loop.

Comment: thanks, it needs a clean-rebuild and worked. where did you get buf[1024] I read a tutorial and he used buf[4096]

Comment: @Milad Great, you're welcome! 1024 was taken out of thin air. 4096 works just as fine.